# JMX port answer in telnet but didn't in jconsole

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, jmx

I'm trying to enable JMX in my kafka connect running under docker. I have the following configs in my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  connect-oracle-jmx:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.2.4
    ports:
     - 8085:8083
     - 9001:9001
    environment:
     - CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka01:9093,kafka02:9093,kafka03:9093
     - CONNECT_GROUP_ID=kafka_connect_oracle_cluster_jmx
     - CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/data/plugins
     - CONNECT_CLIENT_ID=kafka_connect_oracle_cluster_client_jmx
     - CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=_kconnect-oracle-configs-jmx
     - CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=_kconnect-oracle-offsets-jmx
     - CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=_kconnect-oracle-status-jmx
     - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
     - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
     - CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="kafka-connect"
     - CONNECT_PRODUCER_COMPRESSION_TYPE=gzip
     - KAFKA_JMX_PORT=9001
     - KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME=172.17.0.204
    volumes:
     - "/home/uarol/connect/plugins:/data/plugins"
```

Well, the `172.17.0.204` is my host where docker is running. If I try `telnet` outside this host, it works normally:

[image]

But if I try use `jconsole` I got just blank screen without any error or message. I have entered in my docker container and get the command running under `ps -eaf`:

```
java -Xms256M -Xmx2G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.17.0.204 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9001 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9001 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9001 -Dkafka.logs.dir=/var/log/kafka -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties -cp /etc/kafka-connect/jars/*:/usr/share/java/kafka/*:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/*:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/*:/usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/*:/usr/bin/../share/java/confluent-telemetry/* org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed /etc/kafka-connect/kafka-connect.properties
```

And more, if I try `netstat -a | grep LISTEN | grep 9001` in host, it gives me an empty response.

For me, everything seems to be ok, what I'm missing here?

Comment: `172.17.x.x` is typically the Docker bridge network, not your host IP. Generally, people use Prometheus JMX Exporter. At least, that's what the Confluent Helm Charts use.

Comment: My docker is running under 172.18.x.x network